# CORS policy blocking the access to ethereum

Tags: ethereum, web3js

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8545/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Web3js version: 0.20.7

Ran with below command:
`geth --datadir ./peer2DataDir --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "http://127.0.0.1:8080"  --networkid 1114 --port 30303 console 2>> myEth.log`

Comment: How about `--rpccorsdomain "*"`?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin Doesn’t help :(

Answer (score 0):

The bug was introduced in 0.20.7 webjs. Make sure to use 0.20.6, works fine.